# SortWith and custom comparator function

Tags: scala

```
sortKey match {
    case SortKeys.ActualUnits => {
        ResponseList.sortWith {
            (_.aggregations.ActualUnits.get, _.aggregations.ActualUnits.get) =>
            compare(_.aggregations.ActualUnits.get,
                _.aggregations.ActualUnits.get,
                true)
        }
    }
}


def compare(a: BigDecimal, b: BigDecimal, sortOrder: Boolean) = {
    sortOrder match {
        case true => a < b
        case false => b > a
    }
}
```

*aggregations* is a caseclass.

Trying to use a custom comparator function to avoid defining two statements for each sortKey.

Compiler throws `error: not a legal formal parameter`.

Comment: You will have to update your question with your SortKeys code as well so that others can help you with this.

Comment: I suppose you have error with eta expansion. It seems you try to access one placeholder twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 (_.aggregations.ActualUnits.get, _.aggregations.ActualUnits.get) =>
            compare(_.aggregations.ActualUnits.get,
                _.aggregations.ActualUnits.get,
                true)
```

Not really sure what you're trying to do here, but `_.aggregations.ActualUnits.get`, as the error clearly says, is not a a legal formal paramater. I imagine you meant

```
 (x, y) =>
            compare(x.aggregations.ActualUnits.get,
                y.aggregations.ActualUnits.get,
                true)
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I figured that out few minutes ago. Thanks for helping.